# How to read int array (or any array) from object in json

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, json, json.net

So I built working communication between two clients. To sent data I use json, everything is working fine while I am sending single values but when I try do sent whole arrays I don't know how to read them on the receiving part.

```
    Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();        

    data.Add("string", "some string");
    data.Add("int", 234);
    data.Add("bool", true);
    data.Add("intArray", new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });

    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    //sending data through internet as json string

    var newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

    string myString = Convert.ToString(newData["string"]);
    int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(newData["int"]);
    bool myBool = Convert.ToBoolean(newData["bool"]);
    int[] myIntArray = (int[])newData["intArray"]; //doesn't work


    Debug.Log(myString);
    Debug.Log(myInt);
    Debug.Log(myBool);
    Debug.Log(myIntArray);
```

Anyone has idea how to do it?

Comment: Did you google it?

Comment: yeah, couldn't find anything

Comment: What do you mean how does it look like? the json string after serialization? I just use methods provided by Newtonsoft.Json. There is no actual json file saved anywhere, I write and read data on the fly (as shown in the example)

Comment: Consider creating a class where your dictionary keys are the properties, instead of using a dictionary. This would make deserialization easier.

Comment: @Speedo Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the JSON.Net method `ToObject<>()`:

```
var myIntArray = ((JArray) newData["intArray"]).ToObject<int[]>();
```

But a much more cleaner way would be to use a class instead of a `Dictionary<>()`:

*Defining class*

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string MyString {get;set;}
    public int MyInt {get;set;}
    public bool MyBool {get;set;}
    public int[] MyIntArray {get;set;}
}
```

*Using class*

```
var myData = new JsonData{
    MyString = "some string",
    MyInt = 234,
    MyBool = true,
    MyIntArray = new[] {1,2,3}
};

string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);

//sending data through internet as json string

var newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(jsonString);

Debug.Log(newData.MyString);
Debug.Log(newData.MyInt);
Debug.Log(newData.MyBool);
Debug.Log(newData.MyIntArray);
```

Comment: By the way, regarding class use, what if I have few data structures that I send at different times (not exactly one string, int, bool and int array as in example). Do I just make classes for every structure or is there more sophisticated solution?

Comment: I personally like the class approach which is why I usually create a class for every structure I transmit via JSON. Furthermore in the most times a structure is not only transmitted once via JSON, but multiple times during the application life cycle. So classes for every structure are definitely no overkill.